# Passing custom object as selector in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi I have following Object called "rows" that I am trying to pass into jquery function selector.

```
            $("#submit").click(function () {
                   $("#<%=GridView3.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checked").each(function () {
                       var rows = {
                           "pID": $(this).closest('tr').find('.IDName').text(),
                           "Co": $(this).closest('tr').find('.FName').text(),
                       };
                       $("#" + rows).ajaxCustom(
                   "./addAccount.aspx"
                   , function () {  }
                       );
                    });
                 });
               });
```

This $("#" + rows) is not working. Any ideas how to pass that object into ajaxCustom? 
I cant use .ajax and pass in it the data. This custom function only takes url gives response. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is `pID` and `Co`? are they attributes

Comment: pID and Co are the two columns of the gridview. So it takes each row and submits the data to the database.

Comment: perhaps you'd like to close your string with a second `"` after `addAccount.aspx` ?

Comment: Sorry, it was closed I missed it in copy pasting. Thats not the issue

Comment: `$("#"+rowData)` but your variable is called rows, at the moment? And if you were trying to appending the {} object/ dictionary onto the "#" string, why is that going to result in a valid jQuery selector?